# How can I manipulate alert() with a toggle element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some icons with jQuery `toggleClass()` to switch the icons, let's say Icon A and Icon B, when clicked. I also want an alert box to show up ONLY when changing from Icon A to Icon B.

I applied `click()` method together with `alert()` but the alert box simply shows up every time I click the icons (either when switching from Icon A to Icon B or from Icon B to Icon A.)

Is there a way to manipulate the alert box to achieve my goal? Please look at [my pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXodqK) for a clearer example. Thank you.

Comment: please include the code in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the class of the child `i` element when you click your heart. If it has the class `fa-heart` then it's filled:

```
$("a[id^=heart-]").click(function(){
   if($("i", this).hasClass('fa-heart'))
      alert("I need this alert box only when I fill the hearts.");
});
```

[**Updated pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAabwJ)